# JQuery not working on Joomla 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

I am trying to make a simple jQuery script work under Joomla 3. Here is what my module looks now:

```
<?php 
// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
$doc->addScriptDeclaration('
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $(".text").text("By this");
    });
');
?>

<div class="text">Text should be changed...</div>
```

I tried this snippet on a normal page and works perfectly, just I don't know why it does not want to work in Joomla. 
I installed the jQuery Easy plugin as well, but with no success.

Comment: There is no need to install  jQuery Easy plugin for Joomla 3.x

Comment: error: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: have you removed the core jQuery file that comes with Joomla 3.x?

Comment: no, it's a fresh install of j3 with a t3 framework. Haven't touched anything, except I tried the jQuery Easy plugin if it works or not.

Comment: The error you're receiving, does it specify a line? If so I assume it's coming from `JHtml::_('jquery.framework');` which is odd. Try disabling the TS framework to see what difference it makes

Comment: I just put a completely new and fresh joomla 3 without any frameworks and it does exactly the same. The console now shows this:

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready' localhost:8888/fresh/:30
Denying load of chrome-extension://bjgfdlplhmndoonmofmflcbiohgbkifn/js/lib/backbone-min.map. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension. localhost:8888/fresh/:1
Denying load of chrome-extension://bjgfdlplhmndoonmofmflcbiohgbkifn/js/lib/jquery-2.0.2.min.map. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension. localhost:8888/fresh/:1
`

Comment: there is one more thing what shows in the first line:
`(anonymous function) localhost:8888/fresh/:30`

Comment: I'm sure it's something to do with a setting on your localhost server. What do you have `url_allow_fopen` and `url_allow_inclue` set to?

Comment: `allow_url_fopen On`
`allow_url_include Off`

Comment: I do not know what was the problem, but I just added a google's jquery library in the file and now is working. If anyone still knows why the snippet is not working normally, please, can you share your solution?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, finally after a lot of research I have the answer. Because the Joomla is handling jQuery through **namespacing** by default, you have to put it in your jQuery code. It mentions here as well:
http://docs.joomla.org/J3.1:Javascript_Frameworks#jQuery_JavaScript_Framework

So instead of using **$** you have to use **jQuery**. So here is the working code:

```
<?php 
// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');

$doc->addScriptDeclaration('
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery(".text").text("By this :)");
    });     
');
?>

<div class="text">Text should be changed...</div>
```

I hope it helps :)

P.S: You can turn the namespacing off by changing the jQuery declaration like so

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework', false);
```

Please note that this wasn't working for me...

Comment: I think you're missing a ';' before the php end tag. just fyi ;)

Comment: After adding the missing ';' onto your code before the end tag... I got this working fine (Added to my head section of template file). Then just wrote in my jQuery and used the class/id's to control certain HTML attributes on the page. Thanks!