# Bootstrap3 carousel - picking random next slide

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm kind of stumped. :) I'm new to Javascript, but have typically found lots of great help on the net when I Googled.  The best help I could come up with this time was here, but the docs said it was better to post a new question than sidetrack the original post.  So, here's my question:  I'm using Bootstrap3's carousel I'm trying to pick a random starting image, and then continue with random images after that. I've figured out how to pick the first slide, but can't figure out how to pick the next slide. As it stands, it just continues to cycle through the show.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-wrap="true" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- Slider Content (Wrapper for slides )-->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/slides/AAA.jpg" alt="AAA" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/slides/BBB.jpg" alt="BBB" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/slides/CCC.jpg" alt="CCC" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/slides/DDD.jpg" alt="DDD" />
        </div>
        <div class="active item">
            <img src="images/slides/EEE.jpg" alt="EEE" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
     $(document).ready(function() {

         /* Pick a random number and apply it to the first slide in the slideshow item */
         $('.item').eq(Math.floor((Math.random() * $('.item').length))).addClass("active");

         /* Pick random next slide */
         $('#myCarousel').carousel(Math.floor((Math.random() * $('.item').length))));

     });
</script>
```

Thanks. :)

Comment: For me, I saw a lot of examples of this and none worked. Seemed the writing of 'active' did not work or made the carousel completely disappear. But really all I wanted to do was on page load find a random spot from among the 15 or so carousel items I have (not images, sections of text) then the carousel can pick up and play from that point forward. Your simple first random pick script works perfectly for my needs! Now I can finally get to bed. ;-) Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery

```
var currentSlide;
var rand;
$(document).ready(function() {
  currentSlide = Math.floor((Math.random() * $('.item').length));
  rand = currentSlide;
  $('#myCarousel').carousel(currentSlide);
  $('#myCarousel').fadeIn(1000);
  setInterval(function(){ 
    while(rand == currentSlide){
      rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * $('.item').length));
    }
    currentSlide = rand;
    $('#myCarousel').carousel(rand);
  },3000);
});
```

CSS

```
#myCarousel {
    display:none;   
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-wrap="true">
....
```

Well here is an example of how I would do it... I also accounted for the possibility of it randomly changing to the same slide.

http://www.bootply.com/99052

You will notice however that depending on which slide is chosen the carousel will transition either left or right.. The bootstrap carousel was designed to display linear images.  There may be a way to manipulate the order of the items using jQuery so that it always slides the same way.  If you are looking for that it could be done but would take some work and would probably be best handled in another question.

Als you can remove the `data-ride="carousel"` from you html and that will make it so the carousel will initialize without cycling.

Comment: Trevor,  Thanks so much for the code. :)  It was super useful, not only in helping me to understand Java, but it also allowed me to discover that a part of the issue I was having was with Joomla.

Comment: @Ben your welcome, I'm glad that it was useful to you.  If you feel this answer has answered your question please mark it as accepted.  As shown here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work .  Thank you!

Comment: **Update for anybody interested!** Hi everybody,  after @Trevor help, I imported the code into my Joomla site.  After much trouble, I discovered that JQuery and Joomla 3.2 weren't playing nicely together.  None of the typical fixes seemed to work for me.  Yesterday, I stumbled upon this [article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548483/jquery-not-working-on-joomla-3) which gave me a solution that DID work.  It was great to learn that all I had to do was replace the $ with (jquery) and the code worked like magic.

Comment: Good stuff.  Worked great for me.