# Bootstrap Carousel - random order

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using this example for a carousel
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/vvN6a

I would like to randomise the image order. I'm not having much joy. Can anyone help?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20436561/bootstrap3-carousel-picking-random-next-slide

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap3 carousel - picking random next slide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20436561/bootstrap3-carousel-picking-random-next-slide)

Comment: That doesn't work for me. Not sure if I am implementing the jquery correctly.

Answer (score 2):

try adding this::

```
var randomSlide = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('#myCarousel .carousel-inner li').size());

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#myCarousel').carousel(randomSlide);
$('#myCarousel').carousel('next');
});
```