# Adding jquery to Joomla 3.2 template

Tags: jquery, joomla3.0

I would like to add the scroll effect to my page, so that when I click on a menu link, it would go down a page to where it needs to. I have set it up so that when I click on a link it will go to the desired div, but when I tried adding a jquery code to index.php file nothing happens.

I'm using yougrids template and Joomla 3.2.

the div id is yjsg5 so I put in my menu link external link that links to `#yjsg5`. It works since when I click it it goes to that part of the page.

Now in my `index.php` I added this piece of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var $root = $('html, body');
    $('#yjsg5').click(function() {
        var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
        $root.animate({
            scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
        }, 2000, function () {
            window.location.hash = href;
        });
        return false;
    });
    </script>
```

at the end of the `<body>` tag. But that's not working. I've read that they changed something in Joomla 3 with jquery so this may be the reason why it's not working.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery not working on Joomla 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548483/jquery-not-working-on-joomla-3)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your code inside a document.ready block with a namespace alias as an argument:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    ...
});

// or 

jQuery(function($) {
    ...
});
</script>
```

Joomla probably loads jQuery using `noConflict()`, so you can't use `$` unless you do this.

Also, by using this method you can then place your script anywhere on the page. jQuery will wait until the DOM is ready to run it.