# ajax form submit with PHPMailer

Tags: jquery, ajax, phpmailer

I'm trying to submit a form with ajax in order to get the php answer on the same page (http://www.fischer-club.ch/index.php/langschiffrennen/anmeldung). I'm working in joomla with the helix 3 framework, the jquery version is 1.12.4. The helix 3 framwork use Bootstrap 3.
Here my loaded scripts:

```
jquery.min.js?946c71418cf2f59c7cca40b0f1100272
jquery-noconflict.js?946c71418cf2f59c7cca40b0f1100272
jquery-migrate.min.js?946c71418cf2f59c7cca40b0f1100272
caption.js?946c71418cf2f59c7cca40b0f1100272
shaper_helix3/js/bootstrap.min.js
shaper_helix3/js/jquery.sticky.js
shaper_helix3/js/main.js
```

The form pass through php and not through ajax first, i really don't understand why (i get no error from the console). Have i some conflict in the different js scripts? Also bootstrap popovers don't work on my site.

HTML:

```html
<div id="Response"></div>
<form id="AnmeldungLangschiff" action="/pathto/Anmeldung_Langschiff.php" method="POST">
<p><label>Name des Teams</label><input style="width: 300px;" placeholder="Teamname" type="text" name="team_name" required="" /></p>
<p><label>Teamverantwortlicher</label><input style="width: 300px;" placeholder="Vorname Name" type="text" name="teamverantwortlicher" required="" /></p>
<p><label>Email</label><input type="email" style="width: 300px;" placeholder="vorname.name@email.com" name="email_addresse" required="" /></p>
<p><label>Telefon</label><input type="tel" style="width: 300px;" placeholder="+41 79 444 44 44" name="telefon" /></p>
<p><label>Teilnahme an Training</label><br /><input type="radio" name="trainingsteilnahme" value="Ja" checked="checked" /> Ja<br /><label><input type="radio" name="trainingsteilnahme" value="Nein" /> Nein<br /></label></p>
<p><label>Kommentar<textarea style="width: 300px; height: 100px;" name="kommentar" maxlength="500"></textarea></label></p>
<p><button type="submit">Verschicken</button></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var frm = $('#AnmeldungLangschiff');

    frm.submit(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $( "#Response" ).html(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                $( "#Response" ).html(data);
            },
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

PHP:

```html
<?php
/*
PHPMailer laden
*/
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
require '/is/htdocs/www/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';

/*
Wem wird die Form per Email zugestellt?
*/
$empanger_email = 'anymail@gmail.com';

/*
Abholung der Forminformationen.
*/
$team_name = $_POST['team_name'] ;
$teamverantwortlicher = $_POST['teamverantwortlicher'] ;
$email_addresse = $_POST['email_addresse'] ;
$telefon = $_POST['telefon'] ;
$trainingsteilnahme = $_POST['trainingsteilnahme'] ;
$kommentar = $_POST['kommentar'] ;

/*
Verschicken der Email.
*/

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->setFrom('anymail@fischer-club.ch');
$mail->addAddress($empanger_email);
$mail->Subject = 'Anmeldung';
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Body = 'Ciao Seba<br>
Du hast eine Anmeldung zum Langschiffrennen erhalten:<br>
Name des Teams: ' . $team_name . ' <br>
Teamverantwortlicher: ' . $teamverantwortlicher . ' <br>
Email: ' . $email_addresse . ' <br>
Tel.: ' . $telefon . ' <br>
Teilnahme an Training: ' . $trainingsteilnahme . ' <br>
Kommentar: ' . $kommentar . ' <br>
Yves';

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Error";
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}

?>
```

Comment: Wrap your JS code inside DOM ready and make sure it is not placed before the html form.

Comment: thx, but he wrapping inside DOM ready didn't bring an improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a joomla problem! see [JQuery not working on Joomla 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548483/jquery-not-working-on-joomla-3).
In Joomla jQuery is accessed via the jQuery namespace, not through $.